# Why Python Decimal sum is not commutative (different result when I change the order)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, precision

**I am using Decimal with strings to avoid the typical problem**

I have two dictionaries that have the same keys and values but with the keys in a different order. **The sum of the values of these dictionaries should be zero**. However, it is not zero when I sum them in a certain order.

These are my dictionaries and the comparisons I made to make sure the values are the same:

```py
a = {'key_A': Decimal('0'),
    'key_B': Decimal('-1002708'),
    'key_C': Decimal('3965.5752'),
    'key_D': Decimal('991393.8'),
    'key_E': Decimal('-991393.8'),
    'key_F': Decimal('1173.30984201680672268907563'),
    'key_G': Decimal('-7348.6248'),
    'key_H': Decimal('6175.31495798319327731092437'),
    'key_I': Decimal('-741'),
    'key_J': Decimal('0'),
    'key_K': Decimal('4641'),
    'key_U': Decimal('-3900'),
    'key_L': Decimal('1038000'),
    'key_M': Decimal('0'),
    'key_N': Decimal('0'),
    'key_O': Decimal('0'),
    'key_P': Decimal('-3965.5752'),
    'key_Q': Decimal('0'),
    'key_R': Decimal('0'),
    'key_S': Decimal('-15570'),
    'key_T': Decimal('-19722')}

b = {'key_C': Decimal('3965.5752'),
    'key_D': Decimal('991393.8'),
    'key_B': Decimal('-1002708'),
    'key_K': Decimal('4641'),
    'key_U': Decimal('-3900'),
    'key_J': Decimal('0'),
    'key_A': Decimal('0'),
    'key_G': Decimal('-7348.6248'),
    'key_H': Decimal('6175.31495798319327731092437'),
    'key_I': Decimal('-741'),
    'key_R': Decimal('0'),
    'key_N': Decimal('0'),
    'key_T': Decimal('-19722'),
    'key_P': Decimal('-3965.5752'),
    'key_M': Decimal('0'),
    'key_L': Decimal('1038000'),
    'key_F': Decimal('1173.30984201680672268907563'),
    'key_O': Decimal('0'),
    'key_Q': Decimal('0'),
    'key_E': Decimal('-991393.8'),
    'key_S': Decimal('-15570')}

print(sorted(list(a.keys()))==sorted(list(b.keys()))) # "True" so the keys are the same

print(len(a), len(b)) # "21 21" the length are the same


keys = sorted(list(a.keys()))
for k in keys:
 assert a[k]==b[k] # never throws exception so the values are the same

sum_d = lambda d: sum(d[key] for key in d) # a function that sums all the values in a dictionary
```

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM:**

```py
print(sum_d(a), sum_d(b)) # "4E-22 0E-21" EVEN WHEN THE VALUES ARE THE SAME THE SUMS ARE NOT WTF
```

**HERE IS WHEN IT GETS EVEN WEIRDER**
I wanted to make sure this was because of the order, so I inverted the order

```py
a_new = {key:a[key] for key in b.keys()}
b_new = {key:b[key] for key in a.keys()}
  
print(sum_d(a_new), sum_d(b_new)) # "0E-21 4E-22" THE VALUES INVERTED SO IT IS BECAUSE OF THE ORDER
```

So my question is just..... ***WHY...*** why python sum is not commutative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, floating-point arithmetic is not commutative. The `Decimal` class is floating-point.

The default precision for arithmetic operations with `Decimal` is 28 digits. You can change this by altering the context. For example, increase the precision to 40 digits with the following code:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 40
```

If you want to raise an exception for inexact arithmetic, you can configure this explicitly. You might set up the context explicitly, for example:

```
decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(
    traps=[decimal.Inexact],
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two "key_H" keys in `b`.

After removing the line `'key_H': Decimal('6175.31495798319327731092437'),` in `b`, the sum results are the same.

Comment: my bad thanks, in the original diccionary I have some private information, I already correct the question the problem stills the same. Here a link of the code above https://repl.it/talk/share/The-sum-is-not-conmutative/115907